# Return a list of attributes with its values

Tags: generics, abap

I've got multiple tables, defining different attributes.
I am getting the unique id from an external system which requests details for the specified id. Now I would like to create a **factory which serves data providers**. I've already implemented the factory but the data providers are making some troubles. How can I return the return the attributes of a table with its values in a generic way? I've thought of some kind of a propertystore which contains all properties with its names and its values. The problem is to define a return value which provides these attributes in a generic way. 
**How can I implement such a property store?** Or are there any better ways?
I can't define a internal table with a generic type. So **how can I store values of any type in a internal table?**

Answer (score 0):

There is a option "Any Table" for return parameter and internal tables. Well you have to know at least the table name to get the structure of the table.

Here's http://scn.sap.com/thread/1265771 an example!

Cheers
Tobi